Typing reusable components for object fields in react-hook-form
We're having issues using typescript types with  reusable react-hook-form components for object fields with nested inputs. In particular we have trouble with the Path type.
Eschewing reusable components and writing everything inline works, but is not a practical solution. Here's an inline example where name is a localized object containing nested fields with translations in languages en and nb:
import { Controller, useForm, type SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

type ExampleModel = {
  name: { nb: string; en: string };
};


const defaultValues = {
  name: { nb: "nb name", en: "en name" },
}

export const ExampleForm = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm<ExampleModel>({ defaultValues });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ExampleModel> = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller control={control} name="name.nb" render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />} />
      <Controller control={control} name="name.en" render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  );
};

We use the controlled paradigm with Controller in order to integrate with our UI library.
We'd like to define a reusable component LocalizedInput that encapsulates the two inputs. The issue is writing types for the component props so that ${name}.nb and ${name}.en satisfies Path<Model>.
At first glance it looks like FieldPathByValue might do the trick but the error "... is not assignable to type 'Path<Model>'" persists:
import { FieldPathByValue } from 'react-hook-form';

const LocalizedInput = <Model extends FieldValues>({
  control,
  name,
}: {
  control: Control<Model>;
  name: FieldPathByValue<Model, { nb: string; en: string }>;
}) => (
  <>
    <Controller control={control} name={`${name}.nb`} render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />} />
    <Controller control={control} name={`${name}.en`} render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />} />
  </>
);


I find it a bit confusing why that doesn't work, since the following correctly evaluates to type LocalizedPath="name":
type LocalizedPath = FieldPathByValue<ExampleModel, { nb: string; en: string }>;

Any idea how to solve this?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154153/react-hook-form-type-t-is-not-assignable-to-type-pathtfieldvalues. You have to use an as type assertion, and there's no escaping it, unfortunately due to type design of react hook form. Theres also some discussion about this here https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/7354

I see, thanks! Looks like this could be closed as duplicate
